# Running multiple parallel instances of a .NET Core App using dotnet run

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm getting the following error:

> C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.3\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4052,5):
>   warning MSB3026: Could not copy "obj\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MyApp.dll" to
>   "bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MyApp.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The
>   process cannot access the file
>   'C:\stackoverflow\MyApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\MyApp.dll' because it
>   is being used by another process.
>   [C:\stackoverflow\MyApp\MyApp.csproj]

When trying to use `dotnet run` multiple times on the same project from different terminals. How do you easily run multiple instances of the same app while developing, without having to copy the folder?

If I start both at exactly the same time, it sometimes works :/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I've used bat file to run 6 instances of app in one time. Only problem was when I started build of application and immediately run script. So I think you should make sure that build process ended. And then run you bat file with for example dotnet run repeated six times. Your app should be built to execute this file.

```
start /d "." dotnet run args
start /d "." dotnet run args
start /d "." dotnet run args
start /d "." dotnet run args
start /d "." dotnet run args
start /d "." dotnet run args
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Creating 2 (or more) .bat files with each their own "dotnet run x" line in it, doesn't work. Only the first will run, and the subsequent will close down immediately. I need different command line arguments for each instance.

Comment: one file with six occurences:


This is working for me maybe you dont have    Console.ReadLine(); at the end so console is closing immediately

Comment: With start /d "." I see that they indeed open in 2 terminals, unfortunately one of them still immediately closes :/ I guess this is the same as manually opening 2 terminals and executing the commands, but at least when you do it manually the terminal won't automatically close on it's own :/

Comment: I'll try to add Console.ReadLine(); at the end and see if it helps :)

Comment: One of them still closes, even with Console.ReadLine at the end. The App which I'm trying to start 2 instances of, is running until terminated (in this case, only one of them will be doing that, since the other one terminates). I'm surprised that this should be a problem, since I would have expected it to be a rather normal thing to do, when developing console applications with command line arguments.

Comment: i've runnig my instances that way i don't know why your solution doesnt working, maybe try clean and rebuild solution

Comment: It works for one of my applications, but not in my signalr server app which has a `BuildWebHost(args).Run();` in it.

Comment: Ahh I just copied the project and tried running them manually. It seems it exits because of an exception due to the address already being in use. So I guess in order for this solution to work, the app needs to somehow pick another port if already in use. I guess this could be handled with command line params as well, passing the different ports. I'll leave this question open for a day or 2, to see if there're other solutions. Thanks

Comment: yes i think you could change this using  WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseUrls("http://localhost:"+yourport)

Comment: I used something like this. Also, I had an issue with building the same assembly so I added a sleep: ``sleep 10 & dotnet watch run``

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem and solved it using --no-build option:

```
dotnet run --no-build <path to .dll> <args>
```

Please take a look at:
[MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-run?tabs=netcore21)

Comment: This is the correct answer.  You don't need the dll path and you can put your args on either side of --no-build.

Answer (score 2):

The best thing in development time I've found is [dotnet watch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/dotnet-watch) commandline tool.

You could have one bat file which will start multiple `dotnet watch run <project>` commands like [in MateuszWkDev's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48339466/1191799).

Running in watch mode doesn't blocks files from editing and will rebuild and rerun applications once you'll edit your source files automatically.

Suppose you have bat file in `src` folder which has SomeProject, OtherProject and YetAnotherProject folders, which are contains csproj-files. Then bat file could looks like:

```
start /d "%~dp0\SomeProject"       dotnet watch run SomeProject
start /d "%~dp0\OtherProject"      dotnet watch run OtherProject
start /d "%~dp0\YetAnotherProject" dotnet watch run YetAnotherProject
```

Once you run this bat file, you'll got three terminals running `dotnet watch run <project>` commands.

Answer (score 1):

There is one more hacky way by setting **unique** name of build configuration like this:

```sh
start /d "." dotnet run -c Instance1 args
start /d "." dotnet run -c Instance2 args
start /d "." dotnet run -c Instance3 args
start /d "." dotnet run -c Instance4 args
start /d "." dotnet run -c Instance5 args
start /d "." dotnet run -c Instance6 args
```

Moreover, you don't have to specify all your build configurations in the project file (`MyApp.csproj`).

Without setting the name of configuration explicitly the default value is used, which is `Debug`. That is why the DLLs within `Debug` folder are locked.